# Are there dictionary comprehensions in Python? (Problem with function returning dict)

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I know about list comprehensions, what about dictionary comprehensions?

Expected Output:

```
>>> countChar('google')
    {'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'l': 1, 'o': 2}
    >>> countLetters('apple')
    {'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 1, 'p': 2}
    >>> countLetters('')
    {}
```

Code (I'm a beginner):

```
def countChar(word):
    l = []
    #get a list from word
    for c  in word: l.append(c)
    sortedList = sorted(l)
    uniqueSet = set(sortedList)
    return {item:word.count(item) for item in uniqueSet }
```

What is the problem with this code? Why do I get this `SyntaxError`?

```
return { item:word.count(item) for item in uniqueSet }
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The syntax error is the extra `)`: `word.count(item))`

Comment: corrected.but still got problems

Comment: Can you paste the actual error you're getting?

Comment: `from collections import Counter as countChar`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**edit**: As agf pointed out in comments and the other answer, there is a dictionary comprehension for Python 2.7 or newer.

```
def countChar(word):
    return dict((item, word.count(item)) for item in set(word))

>>> countChar('google')
{'e': 1, 'g': 2, 'o': 2, 'l': 1}
>>> countChar('apple')
{'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 'l': 1}
```

There is no need to convert `word` to a list or sort it before turning it into a set since strings are iterable:

```
>>> set('google')
set(['e', 'o', 'g', 'l'])
```

There is no dictionary comprehension with for Python 2.6 and below, which could be why you are seeing the syntax error.  The alternative is to create a list of key-value tuples using a comprehension or generator and passing that into the [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) built-in.

Comment: your code,it too short,it works ,but I am a beginner ,have you other ways for beginner.

Comment: @newbie - I switched it from being a `lambda` to a normal function definition, I will add some additional explanation.

Comment: There ___is___ a dictionary comprehension on Python 2.7 and newer.

Comment: @AndrewClark Your code doesn't demonstrate dictionary comprehensions, it demonstrates the workaround for using Python versions prior to 2.7 (which is useful to those of us running Jython 2.5.3, for example)

Answer (score 67):

If you're on Python 2.7 or newer:

```
{item: word.count(item) for item in set(word)}
```

works fine. You don't need to sort the list before you set it. You also don't need to turn the word into a list. Also, you're on a new enough Python to use `collections.Counter(word)` instead.

If you're on an older version of Python, you can't use `dict` comprehensions, you need to use a generator expression with the `dict` constructor:

```
dict((item, word.count(item)) for item in set(word))
```

This still requires you to iterate over `word` `len(set(word))` times, so try something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def Counter(iterable):
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)
    for item in iterable:
        frequencies[item] += 1
    return frequencies
```

Comment: Python's syntax always makes me feel like I'm cheating. Why aren't other languages this simple?