# How to create a dict with letters as keys in a concise way?

Tags: python, dictionary

I created an dictionary of the 26 alphabet letters like this:

```
aDict={
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    etc...
}
```

I'm trying make my code better and my question is,
is there any shorter way to do this without typing all these numbers out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) and dict comprehension here.

```
In [4]: from string import ascii_lowercase as al
```

For Python 2.7+:

```
In [5]: dic = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(al, 1)}
```

For Python 2.6 or earlier:

```
In [7]: dic = dict((y, x) for x, y in enumerate(al, 1))
```

Comment: How to truncate the alphabet, lets say, with only 10 letters?

Comment: @Sigur Slice it before passing it to enumerate?

Comment: Do you mean *slice the `dic`*?

Answer (score 6):

```
aDict = dict(zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', range(1, 27)))
```

Or instead of hard coding the alphabet:

```
import string
aDict = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, 27)))
```

Comment: If you're not going to hardcode the alphabet, I'd suggest not hardcoding its length, zipping against `itertools.count(1)` or `range(1, 1+len(string.ascii_lowercase))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works in Python 2.6 and older:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
d = {}
for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1):
    d[c] = i
```

If you're using Python 2.7 or newer, you can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276511/are-there-dictionary-comprehensions-in-python-problem-with-function-returning):

```
d = {c : i for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the ascii value of a character using `ord()` function, and the reverse is `chr()`:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```

You can then create a dictionary from the ascii values as follows:

```
for i in range(97, 97+26):
    x[chr(i)] = i - 96
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 and above:

```
import string

letters = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}
```

Python 2.6 and below:

```
import string

letters = dict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1))
```

Comment: Isn't this just @Ashwini's answer?  [Happens to me all the time, too.]

Comment: @DSM Pretty much ... there'll always be a few dupe or near-dupe answers to something like this. I like to imagine everyone furiously typing to get there first :-) Actually I think for this kind of question it's kinda useful; it makes clear to inexperienced readers which are the idiomatic solutions, and which ... aren't.