# How to create a dict with space, quotes, dots, double quotes and etc

Tags: python, dictionary, converters

I saw this question here aDict that includes alphabet but how can I include space, quotes, dots, double quotes as well ?

[How to create a dict with letters as keys in a concise way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902904/how-to-create-a-dict-with-letters-as-keys-in-a-concise-way)

how can include space, quotes, dots, double quotes as well in here? thanks

```
import string
aDict = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1, 27)))
```

Comment: So you want all punctuation as well, or just the one's you specified?

Comment: What would they map to? Your example maps the letters to 1-26, how would you want punctuation mapped?

Comment: based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14902939/989121): `{x:i for i,x in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase+"whatever")}`

Comment: I want to include all punctuation as well which is alphabet and space, quotes, dots, double quotes..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can create a dict with ascii chars as keys and corresponding numbers as values:

```
aDict = { chr(x):x for x in range(129) }
```

Comment: I like that... but 127 is the last ascii character, not 128.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the visible characters by starting with the space character and up to (but not including) the `\x7f` character.

```
{v: k for k, v in enumerate((chr(x) for x in range(ord(' '), ord('\x7f'))), 1)}
```

If you would like to include `\t`, `\n`, and `\r` you can just chain them.

```
import itertools

{v: k for k, v in
 enumerate(itertools.chain(('\t', '\n', '\r'),
                           (chr(x) for x in range(ord(' '), ord('\x7f')))),
           1)}
```