# Extracting key/value pair from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

OK this is a Python question:

We a have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
           ('John', 'Cell3', 5): 0, 
           ('Mike', 'Cell2', 6): 1, 
           ('Peter', 'Cell1', 6): 0, 
           ('John', 'Cell1', 4): 5, 
           ('Mike', 'Cell2', 1): 4, 
           ('Peter', 'Cell1', 8): 9
          }
```

How do you make another dictionary which has only the key/value pair which has the name "Peter" in it?

Does it help if you turn this dictionary to a list of tuples of tuples, by

```
tupled = my_dict.items()
```

and then turn it back to a dictionary again?

How do you solve this with list comprehension?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, using the [dictionary comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276511/are-there-dictionary-comprehensions-in-python-problem-with-function-returning) available in Python 2.7 or newer:

```
{ k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Peter' in k }
```

Alternatively, if we're certain that the name will always be in the first position, we can do this, which is a bit faster:

```
{ k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if k[0] == 'Peter' }
```

If you're using an older version of Python, we can get an equivalent result using generator expressions and the right parameters for the `dict()` constructor:

```
dict((k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items() if k[0] == 'Peter')
```

Anyway, the result is as expected:

```
=> {('Peter', 'Cell1', 8): 8, ('Peter', 'Cell1', 6): 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

for any name

```
def select(d, name):
    xs = {}
    for e in d:
        if e[0].lower() == name.lower(): xs[e] = d[e]

    return xs

d = {('Alice', 'Cell3', 3): 9,
     ('Bob', 'Cell2', 6): 8,
     ('Peter', 'Cell1', 6): 0,
     ('Alice', 'Cell1', 6): 4,
     ('Bob', 'Cell2', 0): 4,
     ('Peter', 'Cell1', 8): 8
    }

print select(d, 'peter')

>>>{('Peter', 'Cell1', 8): 8, ('Peter', 'Cell1', 6): 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{item for item in my_dict.iteritems() if item[0][0].lower() == 'peter'}
```

`.iteritems` iterates over the dict, and we use .lower to match without case sensitivity.